# What not to reveal of OS configuration

Tags: configuration

I thought that I should publicize all my programming on a web page so someone will hire me as a programmer.

I got tempted to include not only programs but my .emacs, .bashrc, and .Xresources files. They show a serious attitude toward tools, as well as some skill in Elisp and shell scripting. (I'm on Debian.)

But then I thought, those files really tell **a lot** about my system, and even about me (what programs I use, how I use them, etc.). So perhaps it is not a good idea?

I realize that you don't know my files, so what I ask for is general guidelines and rules of thumb.

Answer (score 6):

All of these configurations should be default from your distribution and most of them don't have a security impact if read.  If an attacker could modify `.bashrc` then they could pull off a [sudo hijack](http://jo.fabrizio.free.fr/blog/post_00003/index.php),  but just being able to read the `.bashrc` isn't a problem.

Sometimes the `.bash_history` file will contain passwords.  Sometimes passwords are an argument to a command or a user will accidentally type their password into the shell.   The `.keychain` and `.ssh` folders may also contain sensitive information related to authentication.  `.mozilla` contains firefox's cache and may contain personal information.

Answer (score 2):

Taking your question another way, i.e. how to raise your profile as a programmer to get hired.

If you want to be hired as a programmer then I'd recommend setting up a [github repository](https://github.com/) and uploading your scripts/programs to there for everyone to use under an open license such as [Creative Commons](https://creativecommons.org/licenses/).

I'd also recommend becoming involved in Open Source projects where you feel you can add something, depending on whatever language is your forte or where you feel you can most contribute. One only has to look at how successful some of the [Metasploit](http://www.metasploit.com) contributors (and how in demand they are) for a perfect example. Quite a few companies whose product is open-source hire folk who've contributed to the product and given back to the community.

Other companies how folk who do well at hackathons such [HackNY](http://www.hackny.org). If I were you, I'd have a look at such events in your area.

Building up your profile on something like [StackOverflow](http://www.stackoverflow.com) probably isn't a bad idea either.

You'll be amazed what can happen by contributing to the community.

Comment: github: That's more or less what I've done, only problem is that it is a software server so it can only be reached when I'm online. Not very useful so far that is... Perhaps github or some other resource can host it. Thing is, I want it to look my way, I don't want a profile page at a career community. Open Source: I agree 100%, and not just for career but for personal improvement (if there even is a contradiction).